# SQL Query to Check for Duplicates

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a query that is used to check for duplicate addresses (based on having the same address line 1, address line 2 and zip code) but it should not show the records if the transactionType is one of 'Disconnect', 'DeEnrollDeceased', 'DeEnrollLeaving', 'DeEnrollFailedRecertification', 'DeEnrollNonUsage' or if the iehFlag is not set to 0.

So if two records have the same address, but one is 'Disconnect' and the other is not, then neither record should be returned.  Also, if two records have the same address but one is iehFlag = 0 and one is iehFlag = 1, then neither should be returned.  Currently I am getting both returned in both of these cases.

I would greatly appreciate any help on where my query is going wrong

```
SELECT 'Address' DuplicateType, iehFlag, transactionType, AccountNumber, AccountType, firstName, lastName,  last4ssn, tribalId, dob, phoneNumber
FROM table a,
    (SELECT primaryAddress1, COALESCE(primaryAddress2, '') address2, primaryZipCode
    FROM table
    WHERE transactionType NOT IN ('Disconnect', 'DeEnrollDeceased', 'DeEnrollLeaving', 'DeEnrollFailedRecertification', 'DeEnrollNonUsage')
        AND iehFlag = 0
    GROUP BY primaryAddress1, primaryAddress2, primaryZipCode
    HAVING COUNT(AccountNumber) > 1) b
WHERE a.primaryAddress1 = b.primaryAddress1 
    AND COALESCE(a.primaryAddress2, '') = b.address2
    AND a.primaryZipCode = b.primaryZipCode
ORDER BY a.primaryAddress1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 'Address' DuplicateType, iehFlag, transactionType, AccountNumber, AccountType, firstName, lastName,  last4ssn, tribalId, dob, phoneNumber
FROM table a,
    (SELECT primaryAddress1, COALESCE(primaryAddress2, '') address2, primaryZipCode, COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    WHERE iehFlag = 0
    GROUP BY primaryAddress1, primaryAddress2, primaryZipCode
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b
WHERE a.primaryAddress1 = b.primaryAddress1 
    AND COALESCE(a.primaryAddress2, '') = b.address2
    AND a.primaryZipCode = b.primaryZipCode
    AND transactionType NOT IN ('Disconnect', 'DeEnrollDeceased', 'DeEnrollLeaving', 'DeEnrollFailedRecertification', 'DeEnrollNonUsage')
ORDER BY a.primaryAddress1
```

Having the Count(*) in the select clause and the Having clause should correctly tag data that has more than one instance.  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responses.  Try moving your "Where transaction type not in" clause to the outside query.  I've updated my answer to represent this change.

Comment: Also, I know it seems elementary, but make sure those values for transactionType are spelled correctly.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I was finally able to get this to work by rewriting my initial SQL statement with an inner join